# How To Show Number of Posts in WordPress? Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I can’t figure out why this won’t work? I have more than 15 posts but they’re getting cut off the page.

The site: http://gruntsandco.com/

My loop:

```
<?php $latest = new WP_Query('showposts=15'); ?>
<?php while( $latest->have_posts() ) : $latest->the_post(); ?>

Loopageness

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Check the setting in Dashboard -> Reading.

Comment: Yes I also set that to 15. Not sure what the deal is.

Comment: If you disable all plugins, does it still happens? Changing the theme to TwentyTwelve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'posts_per_page' attribute for WP Query.

```
<?php $latest = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=15'); ?>
<?php while( $latest->have_posts() ) : $latest->the_post(); ?>

Loopageness

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If you want to show all posts just set this parametr to -1.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it still limits the count. I'm totally baffled. Tried disabling plugins also.

Comment: Oh boy, I get the dumbass award today. I fixed it. I had the blog using a page template and not index.php. I just set the post_per_page to -1

Comment: @Steven Morgan, IT happens :)